# Possible to make #currentTimeMillis a constant? when a value is added to it?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make the System.currentTimeMillis(); a constant. It's difficult to explain this. What the code is supposed to do is add a value to the System.currentTimeMillis(); which it does and wait till the code returns true and then execute an action. So basically, I'm trying to make a "temp-ban" system. Because System.currentTimeMillis isn't a constant value, of course, this is going to return false. I'm wondering what would I exactly do to make this code become true

```
long timeleft = StaticMaps.muteMap.get(uuid).getTime() * 1000; //seconds to miliseconds
if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= timeleft + System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    plugin.mutemanager.destructPlayerMute(uuid, "Expired", "Removed by Console, Expired!");

} else {
    KTools.notify("debug");
    e.setCancelled(true);
}
```

**Solution I used**
Store the value as a "Long" inside a map with the System.currentTimeMillis(); 
So what you would do is.

```
Map<UUID, Long> temp = new HashMap<>();
Long time = 3 * 1000; //3 * 1000 = 3 Seconds    
temp.put(Identifier, System.currentTimeMillis() + timetoadd)
```

**timetoadd needs to be a long.**

Then check if System.currentTimeMillis() is >= the value in the hashmap.

```
  long HOUR = 3600000;
  long DAY = 86400000;
  long dayformula = Long.parseLong(parts[0]) * DAY;
  long hourformula = Long.parseLong(parts[1]) * HOUR;
  long totalmiliseconds = dayformula + hourformula;
```

Comment: This isn't a thing you're going to be able to do.  What you can and should do is write your own `Clock` class that you can exercise more control over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to make that into a constant.  You want to store off its value for a given moment in time and use that to check against the current system time.

That's easily accomplished thus:

```
long timeleft = StaticMaps.muteMap.get(uuid).getTime() * 1000; //seconds to miliseconds
long lastCheckedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= timeleft + lastCheckedTime) {
    plugin.mutemanager.destructPlayerMute(uuid, "Expired", "Removed by Console, Expired!");

} else {
    KTools.notify("debug");
    e.setCancelled(true);
}
```

...although to be fair, that statement is almost guaranteed to be `false` unless `timeLeft` is on the order of microseconds.

Comment: timeLeft is stored in db as seconds. So I multipled it by *1000 so I can use it as miliseconds

Answer (score 1):

You can't make `System.currentTimeMillis();` a constant (var/value) because that's not a var/value, but rather a function that returns one.

---

What you want to do is save `timestamps` of the current time (using that), plus ban/mute time, into a `map`, and then either `schedule` the *lift* of the ban/unmute, or manage it yourself by periodically checking `System.currentTimeMillis();` and if it's past (above) any expected ban-lift/unmute time (the ones you saved), applying the necessary actions (lifting ban or unmuting).

---

I'm currently on my phone, and I can't give an example of the `schedule` method out of my (not very reliable) memory...

***But***, if it's the managed one, I can ***try***:

```
    //How to "schedule" the lift...
    public /*static ?*/ void mutePlayer(??? uuid, long muteTime){
    StaticMaps.muteMap.put(uuid, System.currentTimeMillis()+muteTime); //I'm assuming how the syntax is...Adapt as needed.
     }

    //Somewhere else, inside a loop that runs periodically...
    for(Entry<uuid, long> scheduled : Staticamaps.muteMap.entrySet()){
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= scheduled.value() /*lift timestamp*/)) {
    plugin.mutemanager.destructPlayerMute(scheduled.key() /*uuid*/, "Expired", "Mute has expired!");
    } else {
    KTools.notify("debug");
    e.setCancelled(true);
    }
    }
```

Note that, since I can't know the syntax or the functions available to `muteMap`, some of the ones I used should be considered `pseudo-code`.